# Creating a folder on a remote server using batch file from teamcity build agent

Tags: batch-file, cmd, teamcity, remote-desktop, xcopy

I am trying to create a folder on a remote machine by running the batch file from teamcity and then copy source into that folder but it seems to be not doing. 
Using following code to create and copy

```
SET dirTempBackup=\\server1\BackupStorage\temp\test
SET Current=\\server1\web\BuildEnvironment\test

 ECHO Starting to copy files.
 IF NOT EXIST "%dirTempBackup%" MKDIR "%dirTempBackup%"
 IF NOT EXIST "!Current!" (
ECHO ERROR! Not found: !Current!
 ) ELSE (
ECHO Copying: !Current!
SET Destination=%dirTempBackup%\!Current:~0,1!
REM Directory.
XCOPY "!Current!" "!Destination!" /v /c /i /g /h /q /r /y /e
)
```

using the temp directory as compressing it later and then deleeting it at the end. Teamcity is generating Access is denied. and Copy failing due to Invalid path. Have checked teamcity user has full rights on that folder.

Comment: What identity is it running under? Has that identity got permissions on the share? (NetworkService would be something like domain\MACHINE$ but LocalService etc. us going to have no rights)

Comment: Also, if you're looking to deploy a website, WebDeploy isnt pain-free but is the right tool for the job

Comment: Thanks..yes checking the permissions on both source and destination fixed the problem.

Comment: @sam please add this as answer and mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checking the permissions on both source and destination fixed the problem.